# Detailview column text to DateTime type property field in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Hi I have an application where I am trying to store a detailview column text to DateTime type property shown as below

```
public DateTime StartDateTime
{
    get { return Convert.ToDateTime(detailview1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text); }
}
```

An exception occurs when detailview1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text has some text other than date format. like '&nbsp'. How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Use DateTime.TryParse first to validate the text as a valid date time.

```
DateTime d ;
DateTime.TryParse("12 Jun 2012", out d);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using if you know your string is not in the correct format regular expression to extract a valid date

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{1,2}\s+?(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\w*\s+?\d{4}"
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
    | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
    | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );

DateTime.Parse(regex.Match(detailview1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text).Groups["date"].Value)
```

Comment: `ParseExact` doesn't have a single parameter overload, plus it will still throw an exception when the text isn't a valid `DateTime`...